# Windows 10 - Blocking a Website in Hosts File

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, blocking, hosts-file

I have blocked a lot of websites in my Windows 10 OS computer and edited the `hosts` file located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`. Below is the content of my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com   
127.0.0.1 www.m.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 www.instagram.com  
127.0.0.1 www.pinterest.ph
127.0.0.1 www.pinterest.com   
127.0.0.1 www.bluestacks.com
127.0.0.1 www.filehorse.com/download-bluestacks/
127.0.0.1 www.bluestacks-app-player.en.uptodown.com/windows
127.0.0.1 www.bluestacks-app-player.en.uptodown.com

127.0.0.1 www.filehippo.com/download_bluestacks_app_player/
127.0.0.1 www.techspot.com/downloads/5342-bluestacks.html
127.0.0.1 www.bluestacksdownloads.com/
127.0.0.1 www.bluestacks.app/
127.0.0.1 www.bluestacks-app-player.en.softonic.com/download
127.0.0.1 www.bluestacks-app-player.en.softonic.com
```

Everything is blocked except `https://m.facebook.com/`. Why is that so? I already blocked it by having a entry `127.0.0.1 www.m.facebook.com` in my `hosts` file.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are blocking `www.m.facebook.com`, not `m.facebook.com`, just add another entry:

> 127.0.0.1 m.facebook.com

to your hosts file.

Answer (score 3):

First, throughout your question, you refer to the file as `host`. Have you created a new file, rather than using `hosts`?

If this was only a typographical error in the question, then try using the IP address, 31.13.71.36, and add a comment, `# www.m.facebook.com`... and please correct your question.

That said, Microsoft has [re-engineered Windows to *ignore* the *hosts* file for certain domains](https://www.petri.com/windows-10-ignoring-hosts-file-specific-name-resolution). MS states this improves security. In any event, using the *hosts* file is not the only way to block an address; use Windows Firewall rules. This is easier to maintain, IMHO, than the somewhat obscure `hosts` file.

A partial list of URL's ignored in *hosts* follows, though Facebook is not in it:

```
www.msdn.com
msdn.com
www.msn.com
msn.com
go.microsoft.com
msdn.microsoft.com
office.microsoft.com
microsoftupdate.microsoft.com
wustats.microsoft.com
support.microsoft.com
www.microsoft.com
microsoft.com
update.microsoft.com
download.microsoft.com
microsoftupdate.com
windowsupdate.com
windowsupdate.microsoft.com
```